# HOW do i delete a symbol from a char array(not string array)

Tags: c++, arrays, char, client-server

I have a client-server program where client sends a char array and server deletes 3 first and 2 last symbols(not including 0-terminator) if length of the array is even and sends that array back to the client

the thing is idk how to delete a particular symbol from the array of chars (im not actually good at working with pointers and i guess using them might be a solution here)
here's the part of the code that is problematic:

```
 while (recv(s, b, sizeof(b), 0) != 0) //while connection is open
    {
        l = strlen(b); 
        if (l%2==0)//if length is even
        {
            for (i = j = 0; i < l; i++) 
            {
                ch = b[i]; //current symbol
                if (i!=0 || i!=1 || i!=2 || i!=l-1 || i!=l-2)
                {
                    b[j++] = ch; // if the symbol fots the condition
                }
            }


        }
        else
        {
            strcpy_s(b, "The string is odd ");
        }
        send(s, b, sizeof(b), 0); //sending the result
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide before/after examples of the behavior you want?

Comment: sending: qazwsxedc1
recieving: wsxed

Comment: Why is this tagged as C++ when the code is obviously C. In C++ you'd do this very differently.

Comment: @Sasha "thats cpp" - I disagree. First of all, you wouldn't normally use a C-style array in C++. You'd use a `std::array` or `std::vector`. Also, you probably wouldn't use `sizeof` since you wouldn't need to, and if you wanted to know the number of elements in some container, you'd use `.size()` or `std::size`. This code looks like C that just happens to be buildable with a C++ compiler.

Comment: What does it mean "to delete a symbol" from an array of chars? An array of n-chars is an array of n-chars. You can change the value of a char at a given location but to delete it doesn't quite make sense. What you can do it move the pointer forward by m-chars and pretend the array is l-chars shorter than it really is. That's about it. Looks like its dust of the chapter on pointers.

Comment: If you're using C-strings, you should always send the size instead of relying on the function `strlen()` working. C-strings will break at the drop of a hat, so the more safety you build in, the better.

Answer (score 1):

The first two code examples assume that the original C-string is not needed after the trimming takes place. Just because it's a touch easier that way. The last example keeps the original strings intact, but they can be assigned to themselves if you only care about the updated values.

"C++"

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

void trim(char buf[], int size) {
  if (size > 5) {
    std::strncpy(buf, &buf[3], size - 5);
    buf[size - 6] = '\0';  // sizeof() counts the null character
  }
}

int main() {
  char too_small[] = "abc";       // Expect same back
  char small[] = "abcdefgh";      // Expect def
  char example[] = "qazwsxedc1";  // Expect wsxed

  trim(too_small, sizeof(too_small));
  trim(small, sizeof(small));
  trim(example, sizeof(example));

  std::cout << too_small << '\n' << small << '\n' << example << '\n';
}
```

C (Your C++ compiler compiles it, but your code is C)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void trim(char buf[], int size) {
  if (size > 5) {
    strncpy(buf, &buf[3], size - 5);
    buf[size - 6] = '\0';  // sizeof() counts the null character
  }
}

int main() {
  char too_small[] = "abc";       // Expect same back
  char small[] = "abcdefgh";      // Expect def
  char example[] = "qazwsxedc1";  // Expect wsxed

  trim(too_small, sizeof(too_small));
  trim(small, sizeof(small));
  trim(example, sizeof(example));

  printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", too_small, small, example);
}
```

C++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string trim(std::string str) {
  return str.size() > 5 ? str.substr(3, str.size() - 5) : str;
}

int main() {
  std::string too_small("abc");       // Expect same back
  std::string small("abcdefgh");      // Expect def
  std::string example("qazwsxedc1");  // Expect wsxed

  std::cout << trim(too_small) << '\n'
            << trim(small) << '\n'
            << trim(example) << '\n';
}
```

It's likely that the other answer runs more efficiently than these examples, but I wanted to post mostly to highlight some striking differences between C and C++ and how the problem can be tackled very differently between the two languages.

Comment: thanks, these code examples really helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple program which demonstrates how to deal with character arrays.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

int main() {

        /* our input string */
        char *in = "qazwsxedc1";

        /* declare storage for our output string and initialise it */
        char out[500];
        memset(out, 0, 500);

        /* get length of input string */
        unsigned short len = strlen(in);

        /* copy from input string to output */
        strncpy(out, in + 3, len - 3 - 2);

        /* prove that the data were copied */
        printf("Input: %s\n", in);
        printf("Output: %s\n", out);

        /* terminate program */
        return 0;

}
```

The trick is not to delete characters from the array but instead select the ones you want. Future improvements: check the input string is longer than 5 characters. (If not you'll copy garbage into your output string.)